# C++ nuGet packages in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, nuget, allegro5

How do I install nuGet packages for c++ in vs code? I've tried installing allegro library using nuGet plugin, but is seems to only work for c# projects, and says that it didn't find any .csproj files in the project.

Comment: Can't you make your question a bit more informative? What is the exact error, message, thing you are facing? Help others help you.

Comment: It says that it can't find any .csproj or .fsproj file for your project

Comment: Sure. Just edit your post and add as much information as you can.